# How make 4 items fit perfectly inside the container

Tags: html, css

Codepen - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZGYQej

I need to make 4 items fit perfectly inside a container and each item must have 5px margin of the other. I'm trying to do but it is never perfect, what do I mean by perfect? The first item should be in the far left, and the last at the far right, and yet the four items need to be far apart with 5px .

Code:

HTML:

```
<section class="statistics">
        <div class="container">
          <h2 class="statistics__title">Estátisticas</h2>
          <ul class="statistics__list">
            <li class="statistics__item"></li>
            <li class="statistics__item"></li>
            <li class="statistics__item"></li>
            <li class="statistics__item"></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-right: 3%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.statistics__title {
  margin: 15px 15px 15px 0;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
.statistics {
  width: 100%;
}
.statistics__list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.statistics__item {
  margin: 0 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 23%;
  height: 230px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
```

Comment: I don't see the problem here, ¿you want this to be responsive or static?

Comment: static.. the container is not perfectly, that's the problem.

Comment: try to add: min-width: 900px to the container, the issue with using percentage widths, is that its meant to change according to screen size, if you want to keep the same layout don't use it, or add min-width to the container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try usin the pseudo-class `:last-child` on `.statistics__item`

This way you can give all elements `margin-right:5px` except for the last element, causing the first item to be in the far left, and the last at the far right while the four items are seperated with a margin of 5px.

```css
box-sizing:content-box;
  padding-left:3%;
  padding-right:3%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
.statistics__title {
  margin: 15px 15px 15px 0;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
.statistics {
  width: 100%;
}
.statistics__list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.statistics__item {
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 23%;
  height: 230px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
.statistics__item:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<section class="statistics">
  <div class="container">
    <h2 class="statistics__title">Estátisticas</h2>
    <ul class="statistics__list">
      <li class="statistics__item"></li>
      <li class="statistics__item"></li>
      <li class="statistics__item"></li>
      <li class="statistics__item"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first child have a `margin-left: 0px` too?

Comment: No. When using `margin-right:5px` there will be no `margin-left`. But u can use it to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

This possible solution involves CSS [**`flexbox`**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), check out the demo below.

```css
.statistics__title {
    background: silver;
}
.statistics__list {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 -5px; /*get rid of the left margin on 1st item, and right margin on 4th item*/
    display: flex;
}
.statistics__item {
    background: gold;
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<section class="statistics">
    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="statistics__title">Estátisticas</h2>
        <ul class="statistics__list">
            <li class="statistics__item">1</li>
            <li class="statistics__item">2</li>
            <li class="statistics__item">3</li>
            <li class="statistics__item">4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/b0t9m95L/

Comment: **Note**: the silver background on the title is just for measuring purpose, to see/know that the yellow items are taking the entire width dynamically on any window size :)